# SQL Server query return next date with an event

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basic SQL question but I have a mind blank. I have a table with the following setup:

```
date          eventType
-----------------------
01/01/2016    0
02/01/2016    0
03/01/2016    2
03/01/2016    2
04/01/2016    6
04/01/2016    6
04/01/2016    6
04/01/2016    6
05/01/2016    0
06/01/2016    ...
```

I want to return the "next set of events where eventType<>0"

So, if "today" was 01/01/2016, the query would return:

```
03/01/2016      2
03/01/2016      2
```

If "today" was 03/01/2016, the query would return:

```
04/01/2016      6
04/01/2016      6
04/01/2016      6
04/01/2016      6
```

Etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a different solution, check this:

```
DECLARE @dtEventType DATE = '20160101'

DECLARE @table TABLE ( cDate DATE , eventType TINYINT )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES( '20160101' , 0 ) 
, ( '20160102' , 0 )
, ( '20160103' , 2 )
, ( '20160103' , 2 )
, ( '20160104' , 6 )
, ( '20160104' , 6 )
, ( '20160104' , 6 )
, ( '20160104' , 6 )
, ( '20160105' , 0 )

SELECT * 
FROM @table L
WHERE cDate = ( 
    SELECT MIN( cDate ) AS mnDate
    FROM @table
    WHERE eventType <> 0
    AND cDate > @dtEventType
)
```

But I liked the @GordonLiff's 3rd solution .

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks. It was the `WHERE date = (SELECT ... )` I was after. Thanks for fixing the mind block

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I think this may be a bit trickier than it seems.  This does what you want for the data in the question:

```
select e.*
from events e cross join
     (select top 1 eventType
      from events
      where date > getdate() and eventType <> 0
      order by date
     ) as nexte
where e.date > getdate() and
      e.eventType = nexte.eventType;
```

Or, perhaps a better fit:

```
select e.*
from events e cross join
     (select top (1) e.*
      from events
      where date > getdate() and eventType <> 0
      order by date
     ) as nexte
where e.date > nexte.date and
      e.eventType = nexte.eventType;
```

Or, more simply:

```
select top (1) with ties e.*
from events e
where date > getdate() and eventType <> 0
order by date, eventType
```

Comment: I want to limit cross joins as the data sets are large, however, your 3rd solution would return just one record, no?

Comment: That's wrong, "WITH TIES may cause more rows to be returned than the value specified in expression" , please check the WITH TIES option for TOP clause. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: I never knew about `WITH TIES`. I went with @chancrovsky's solution, but +1 for the tip. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
SELECT eventDate, event 
FROM events
WHERE eventDayte > GETDATE()+1 -- limit here to datePart date to avoid confusion with time as this can lead to issues
-- we should provide limit here to avoid return all future events 
AND eventDate <= GETDATE()+2
AND eventType<>0
```